# Removing the rows from the select after processing

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to a table like this

```
Year Month
2012  8
2012  7
2012  4
2012  3
2011  7
2011  3
2011  1
2010  10
2010  9
2010  8
```

This tables show which month and year is remaning, now let say I have completed 2012, 7 month. Now I want to have list like

```
Year Month
    2012  8
    2012  4
    2012  3
    2011  7
    2011  3
    2011  1
    2010  10
    2010  9
    2010  8
```

I am using below query but this is not giving me the correct records

```
SELECT YEAR, MONTH from tablex
WHERE Year NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR from OTHER_TABLE INNER JOIN Some_Other_Table)
AND  MONTH NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MONTH FROM OTHER_TABLE INNER JOIN Some_Other_Table)
```

When OTHER_TABLE is null then I am getting the currect count, but when Other table has year 2012 and month 7 I am getting no results.

**P.S.: There is no joining columns available for tablex and OTHER_TABLE and Som_Other_Table**

Comment: Are you getting *no results* or *too few results*? What rows do you have in `OTHER_TABLE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
SELECT YEAR, MONTH 
from tablex t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM OTHER_TABLE t2
    WHERE t2.Year = t1.Year AND t2.Month = t2.Month 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes you have a single row `{Year = 2012, Month = 7}` in `OTHER_TABLE` to designate the completed month.

This won't work because you're checking the year and month separately. Therefore you are not removing the row (2012, 7) from the results, you're removing all rows with Year = 2012 and all rows with Month = 7. Try this anti-join instead:

```
SELECT x.YEAR, x.MONTH
FROM tablex x
LEFT OUTER JOIN OTHER_TABLE y ON x.YEAR = y.YEAR AND x.MONTH = y.MONTH
WHERE y.YEAR IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there any other way around as I have already have struncture like this 
*SELECT FROM MainTable WHERE Col1 (SELECT FROM TABLEA INNER JOIN TABLEB)
AND Col2(SELECT FROM TABLEA INNER JOIN TABLEB)*

WHere MainTable has no joining condition with TableA and TableB

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite I'm not sure I entirely follow. Can you post all relevant tables structure and some sample data, as well as this query?